# Thermionic cathode heater filament conundrum

Tags: crt

An old CRT I have specifies 6.3 V (DC, *I believe*) on the heater filament, resulting in a 0.6 A filament current (spec).

But I measure the filament resistance as 1.8 Ohm.

At V = 6.3 V that would result in a 3.5 A filament current, about 6 times too high!

I'm tempted to measure the filament current with a 6 V DC battery pack but I'm afraid to burn the filament?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: If you try ... do it slowly. The filament must be "just" a little "red", ... if you see it ...

Comment: Also at 6.3V, the supply was usually AC (though DC would work and it was designed to be compatible with 3 cell Lead Acid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.8 ohms is the cold resistance; it will increase as the filament warms to operating temperature.

Comment: Ah. That solves it. I didn't think the effect of temperarure would be *that* large. Accepted.

Comment: It's probably >6x R increase at 1500'K